# Can't use background task in Windows Phone 8.1 (the ID_CAP_NETWORKING required, but it's included in the manifest)

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, live-tile, background-task

I need to update my Windows Phone application tile by downloading and parsing JSON. So I'm using Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries.

And I've always got the exception `Use of networking APIs requires the ID_CAP_NETWORKING capability to be defined in the application manifest` when I'm trying to debug background task.

But my manifest included ID_CAP_NETWORKING as required (screenshot https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t31.0-8/10750111_821340111262044_6461333323674658178_o.jpg).

I don't know what to do. I tried rebuild or recreate the app, but this didn't help. Also I can't find any documentation or an answer on the internet.

Can you please write, what can I do to solve this problem?

This is demo project http://1drv.ms/1yjHm49 with reproduced problem (project's name is 'Meduza. Windows Phone').

I debug my application on Lumia 720 (if it can help).

Comment: Ran you app, no exceptions got thrown.  Long shot, but can you enabled `Internet (Client and Server)` in the Package.appxmanifest file?

Comment: Did you run `UpdateTileBackgroundTask` (screenshot http://i.imgur.com/cEESNxl.png)? Enabling `Internet (Client and Server` didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-downloaded your project and now I get your error.  So I thought, I must of done something before launching your project that fixed it.

It took me while, but I can get your project to work by doing this

> Unzip project to directory
> Open Project
> Clean Project
> Add **Internet (Client and Server)** in Package.appxmanifest file (make sure you save it before exiting)
>
> Put the break points in your background task

And it works.  So a combination of Clean Build + editing the Package.appxmanifest did the trick for me.